# Dead code analysis in VisualStudio 2013 Pro

Tags: visual-studio, resharper, dead-code, unused-variables

I need to remove unused variables and functions(Deadcode) in a c code. Can I use VisualStudio 2013 Pro code analysis to find unused c variables? Because in the rule set, Microsoft.Performance rules are not available for unmanaged code. is there any other tool I can use to find deadcode in c? Will ReSharper help?